# Joining a count query mysql for performance

Tags: php, mysql

Have searched but can't find an answer which suits the exact needs for this mysql query.

I have the following quires on multiple tables to generate "stats" for an application:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM `mod_**` WHERE `published`='1';

SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM `mod_***` WHERE `published`='1';

SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM `mod_****`;

SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM `mod_*****`;
```

pretty simple just counts the rows sometimes based on a status.

however in the pursuit of performance i would love to get this into 1 query to save resources.

I'm using php to fetch this data with simple `mysql_fetch_assoc` and retrieving  `$res[count]` if it makes a difference (pro isn't guaranteed, so plain old mysql here).

Answer (score 5):

The overhead of sending a query and getting a single-row response is very small.

There is nothing to gain here by combining the queries.

---

If you don't have indexes yet an `INDEX` on the `published` column will greatly speed up the first two queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
SELECT SUM(published=1)
```

for some of that. MySQL will take the boolean result of `published=1` and translate it to an integer `0` or `1`, which can be summed up.

But it looks like you're dealing with MULTIPLE tables (if that's what the `**`, `***` etc... are), in which case you can't really. You could use a `UNION` query, e.g.:

```
SELECT ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
UNION ALL 
SELECT ...
etc...
```

That can be fired off as one single query to the DB, but it'll still execute each sub-query as its own query, and simply aggregate the individual result sets into one larger set.

Answer (score 0):

As @Halcyon said there is not much to gain here. You can anyway do several UNIONS to get all the result in one query

Answer (score 0):

Disagreeing with @Halcyon I think there is an appreciable difference, especially if the MySQL server is on a different machine, as every single query uses at least one network packet.

I recommend you UNION the queries with a marker field to protect against the unexpected.